# 502 error with nginx + uwsgi +django

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I've tried to configure django on top on nginx and uwsgi and a 502 bad gateway error is encountered when trying to access localhost

This is my /etc/ngingx/sites-available/default file

```
server {
    server_name testapp1.com www.testapp1.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/testapp1.com.access.log;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:///var/run/uwsgi/app/testapp1/socket;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

This is my testapp1.ini file in /etc/nginx/apps-available/

```
[uwsgi]  
    thread=3  
    master=1  
    env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testapp1.settings  
    module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()  
    chdir = /home/paul/apps/testapp1  
    socket = /run/uwsgi/testapp1/socket  
    logto = /var/log/uwsgi/testapp1.log
```

This is the uwsgi.log file

> Tue Jul 10 21:49:38 2012 - *** Starting uWSGI 1.0.3-debian (32bit) on
>   [Tue Jul 10 21:49:38 2012] *** Tue Jul 10 21:49:38 2012 - compiled
>   with version: 4.6.2 on 20 February 2012 10:06:16 Tue Jul 10 21:49:38
>   2012 - current working directory: / Tue Jul 10 21:49:38 2012 - writing
>   pidfile to /run/uwsgi/app/testapp1/pid Tue Jul 10 21:49:38 2012 -
>   detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core Tue Jul 10 21:49:38 2012 -
>   setgid() to 33 Tue Jul 10 21:49:38 2012 - setuid() to 33 Tue Jul 10
>   21:49:38 2012 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes Tue Jul 10
>   21:49:38 2012 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address
>   /run/uwsgi/app/testapp1/socket fd 5 Tue Jul 10 21:49:38 2012 - bind():
>   No such file or directory [socket.c line 107]

I didnt change the nginx.conf file.

Comment: Please post nginx logs. It is very likely that nginx cannot connect to uWSGI. In that case, either use a port, either [fix permissions](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19240900759/survive-linux-nix-permissions).

Comment: Are these socket definitions the same?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error message is clear enough:

```
Tue Jul 10 21:49:38 2012 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address
/run/uwsgi/app/testapp1/socket fd 5
Tue Jul 10 21:49:38 2012 - bind():
No such file or directory [socket.c line 107]
```

Do you see difference between:

```
 socket = /run/uwsgi/testapp1/socket
```

and:

```
 uwsgi_pass unix:///var/run/uwsgi/app/testapp1/socket;
```

?

*Hint:* /**var**/run/uwsgi/**app**/testapp1/socket

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - yeah that was a silly mistake from my part to give different paths to the socket file - copy paste issue :)

Answer (score 22):

Other case scenario is that it is a permission problem (not a socket path misspell like in your case). In that case u can add this to uwsgi ini file

```
[uwsgi]                                                                                                          
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
chmod-socket = 664
chown-socket = www-data
```

Comment: I needed this `chown-socket = www-data` and I couldn't figure it out for the life of me!  Thanks for this!!  As a side note, I think setting the file permissions for the socket to 664 (or at most 666) should be sufficient.

Comment: @zzart : I've replicate this setup but the socket is still created by the logged-in user instead of www-data. Additionally, uwsgi fails to start with the error message `chown(): Operation not permitted`

Comment: @buffer I also found that you cannot use chown-socket in uwsgi.ini