# Django app with Nginx + uWSGI on Amazon EC2

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, wsgi, uwsgi

I am trying to set a Django app on Amazon EC2 using Nginx + uWSGI.

Following basic these tutorials

https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html
http://www.yaconiello.com/blog/setting-aws-ec2-instance-nginx-django-uwsgi-and-mysql/#sthash.TsdnEDM8.oK2geOwb.dpbs

Nginx welcome page appears ok, Instance is running, Loadbalancer is In Service, Route53 alias to loadbalancer. But I can't see my app...

It appears that the app is running. I have tested local and it works.

I typed on terminal

```
uwsgi --ini myproject_uwsgi.ini
```

And get this

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from myproject_uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 1.9.15 (64bit) on [Wed Sep 11 06:14:04 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.7.3 on 10 September 2013 09:27:00
os: Linux-3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013
nodename: ip-10-252-80-160
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/ubuntu/myproject
writing pidfile to /tmp/myproject-master.pid
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 4569
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
 *** WARNING: you have enabled harakiri without post buffering. Slow upload could be rejected on post-unbuffered webservers *** 
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/myproject.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:30:41)  [GCC 4.7.3]
Set PythonHome to /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myproject
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1235b30
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 363880 bytes (355 KB) for 4 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x1235b30 pid: 1500 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1500)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 1501, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 1502, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 1503, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 1504, cores: 1)
```

And I try to see the error.log and I get nothing...

EDIT

myproject_uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
chdir = /home/ubuntu/myproject
module = myproject.wsgi
home = /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myproject
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings

# process-related settings
master = true
processes = 4
socket = /tmp/myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 664
harakiri = 20
vacuum = true
max-requests = 5000
pidfile = /tmp/myproject-master.pid
daemonize = /home/ubuntu/myproject/log/myproject.log
```

myproject_nginx.conf

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/myproject.sock;
    # server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

# configuration of the server
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myproject.com www.myproject.com;
    charset utf-8;

    root /home/ubuntu/myproject/;

    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /media {
        alias /home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/myproject.sock;
        include /home/ubuntu/myproject/uwsgi_params;
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: Can you add your myproject_uwsgi.ini and nginx config files?  Also, when you do that, can you either daemonize it, or open another terminal to the same box and make a request to localhost?

Comment: @sberry I have added myproject_uwsgi and myproject_nginx.conf. The other things I am trying... sorry newbie here

Comment: I added daemonize to myproject_uwsgi.ini and I typed tail -f myproject.log and get almost the same thing when I type uwsgi myproject_uwsgi.ini

Comment: What error do you see when you hit the page ?

Comment: @Amit I still couldn't make the app works almost gave up yesterday... I can see acess-log but error-log is always empty. Started again with out LoadBalancer and Route53... only Ec2 instance and Securiy group... set security group to listen 80 without amazon default settings, 22 and 8000 all to 0.0.0.0 to test. I can see app working when manage.py runserver. I also put a line error_log on my myproject_nginx.conf but it is not created. The sockets are being created can see it on tmp directory. I also make it works with uwsgi yesterday but I forgot the commands :(... this night will be long again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally make my app works... first I made it works with TCP, test on port 8001 but the static files was getting error 404. So I want to have at least the app working through unix sockets even with no static files...

I started changing the nginx.conf and uwsgi.ini to sockets and started receiving error 502. Much better than yesterday errors (unable to connect).

Searching and reading through web and SO... found this [502 error with nginx + uwsgi +django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430185/502-error-with-nginx-uwsgi-django?rq=1)

Can't vote neither comment. But thanks @zzart !!

So added to my uwsgi.ini

```
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
chmod-socket = 777
```

I have added yesterday the uid (www-data), gid(www-data) and chmod-socket = 664 or 644. But not worked for me on Amazon EC2. But 777 make it works and also static files working too.

Now I will drink a beer and tomorrow will change security groups, loadbalancer and route53.

Hope it helps others.

Comment: I have read about security with 777 and tried 775. It worked for me on EC2.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Example used FastCGI Deamon in Amazon EC2

```
    django.sh  -> https://gist.github.com/romuloigor/5707566
    nginx.conf -> https://gist.github.com/romuloigor/5707527
```

Comment: your example is pretty complete, I want to go with wsgi but I will make a test with your gist. Obrigado @romuloigor

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use wsgi? I use fastcgi! I'm doing it right?

Comment: I am trying uWSGI because read good things about performance. There are some posts about wsgi vs fastcgi here and on web... I think you are doing right since it is working for you @romuloigor